# combining two dict_key instances with preserving their order

Tags: python, dictionary, key, union

I have two dict with different keys. I would like to combine both keys into a list or something so that I can iterate over. However the order is important because at some places of the script I need to preserve the order for other calculations via `enumerate()`

Here is a small example of what I am trying to do:

```
ns.keys()
Out[1]: dict_keys([108])
no.keys()
Out[2]: dict_keys([120, 124, 126, 127, 112, 114, 115, 117, 118, 135, 132, 133, 109, 130, 111, 129, 136])
```

I want to iterate over both of them like following:

```
for key in [ns.keys() | no.keys()]:
    print(key)
Out[3]: {129, 130, 132, 133, 135, 136, 108, 109, 111, 112, 114, 115, 117, 118, 120, 124, 126, 127}
```

The order is important because, I also want to do following:

```
for i, key in enumerate([ns.keys() | no.keys()]):
    print(i, key)
```

I want the order of `[ns.keys() | no.keys()]` to be first `ns.keys()` then `no.keys()`. In this example, it should be:

```
[108, 120, 124, 126, 127, 112, 114, 115, 117, 118, 135, 132, 133, 109, 130, 111, 129, 136]
```

Following works `list(ns.keys()) + list(no.keys())`, any other idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just unpack dict keys within a list for iteration:

`[*ns.keys(), *no.keys()]`

Comment: Ahh, this is really elegant! Thanks. Much better than just adding two dict_keys after converting them to lists...

Answer (score 1):

You can use chain:

```
from itertools import chain

a = {"a": 2}
b = {"b": 2, "c": 3}

for i, key in enumerate(chain(a, b)):
    print(i, key)
    
    
# 0 a
# 1 b
# 2 c
```

This is a memory-efficient way of doing, if your dicts are large.

Comment: This is the best answer, because it doesn't create an intermediate data structure in memory.

Answer (score 0):

You dont' event need to use the keys() method. enumerating or unpacking dictionaries returns the keys directly:

```
for i,key in enumerate([*ns,*no]):
    print(i,key)
```